# Does IronRuby have a CodeDomProvider?

Tags: code-generation, ironruby, codedom

If not is one scheduled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're not currently looking to implement a CodeDom provider. However, someone else could do it, and if others find it useful I see no reason why not to merge it in.

It would help me to understand specifically what you would use it for.

Comment: Jimmy

I would like to use if for code generation. ATM i am using almost exactly the same code for generating code in C# VB and F#. But for IronRuby I need to do a fair amount of custom code.

Comment: I also need it to generate code for IronRuby--I already have a framework for generating CodeDom trees--the only thing missing here is the hypothetical IronRubyCodeDomProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Can't seem to find any reference to one in the current source. However in [this post](http://www.iunknown.com/2007/07/a-first-look-at.html) some years back, John Lam said that it was something they would be looking to add in the future

Comment: Conrad. U missed the "l" off your link 
http://www.iunknown.com/2007/07/a-first-look-at.html
And i did see that one and should have included the link in the question. But it is two years ago. I was hoping for something a bit more definitive than "on the roadmap to implement".

Answer (score 0):

it has many things to do what a codedomprovider would do. By nature it is dynamic which means that you have some powerful tools to your disposal. These include things like eval which allows you to execute arbitrary code etc.

Comment: Yes but the idea of a CodeDomProvider is that you can write the same generation code and it will work for any language. Without a “IronRubyProvider” I will have to treat iron ruby as a special case.